# How do you get NTP time in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Can someone show me an example of how to get NTP from a NTP server stats using Elixir ?

Comment: Here's an example in Erlang, should be quite easy to port to Elixir. It shows how to destructure a NTP packet, however does not implement the actual NTP algorithm. github.com/mnp/erlang-ntp